# Include an array of 20k zip codes or call MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of about 20,000 zip codes that I need to check against. Should I store them in an PHP file as an array? How much memory would that occupy?

Or should I call MySQL every time to check against its database table to see if it exists? Which way is faster? I assume the first option should be faster? The connection to database alone may slow down the database call option quite significantly? I'm just a bit concerned about that memory problem if I do it by including PHP file on every call.

Comment: [You can work out yourself exactly hw much memory an array will take](https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html)... be warned, 20000 zip codes will take a ___lot___ of memory, all of which needs allocating/deallocating, which takes time.... you may well find that a database is far more efficient, especially if it's properly indexed

Comment: "The connection to database alone may slow down the database call option quite significantly?" LOL. Give me a break. If it does you can look into query caching or something.

Comment: If your list is tab separated file or similar, you can do a LOAD DATA INFILE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html Edit: Which I think is what @MarkBaker had in mind.

Comment: As the other comments indicate, you need to do some work on this yourself.  I would make it a RESTful service and query it via AJAX and hit the database to return all postcodes with that pattern after say two or three characters onKeyUp (depending on how long your postcodes are) in the textfield as a JSON object.  You can then match on that much smaller array client-side using javascript.

Comment: @MarkBaker, Thank you for your constructive comment! It is indeed big.

Comment: @MarkBaker 20,000 integers is not really "a lot of memory". The reason why you'd put it in memory in the first place is debatable, but the memory impact is inconsequential.

Comment: Before you start policing what a valid zip code is, and what a valid zip code isn't, which is a battle you really can't win since the world isn't static and things change all the time, you may want to consider what your goal is here. Normally it's best to warn someone that their zip code *may* be invalid rather than reject it. Don't forget there's countries outside the US that also have postal systems that differ considerably.

Comment: @tadman - 20000 integers, each stored in a zval, with all the additional overheads of an array element and the array itself... this isn't simply 8k of integer data, it's closer to 8MB of memory usage, which isn't insubstantial.... and the array would have to be indexed on the zip to give any benefit (an isset check - O(1) - rather than using in_array - O(n)), and partial searches would be O(n) as well

Comment: @MarkBaker You can use an associative array, but I doubt scanning this list once every time a form is submitted would be a big deal. While I agree it's sub-optimal, 8MB of memory is basically inconsequential these days for a one-off cache. Even a thrifty $5/mo. VPS will come with 1024-2048MB of memory available for use. The real problem here is PHP compilation times and the utility of such a lookup table in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Databases are specifically designed to store and search through large amounts of data efficiently and quickly. If you were to put a 20,000 element array in every PHP file it would drastically slow down every page load, even when the array wasn't being used.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM zip_codes WHERE code=?` is not going to be all that slow if it's indexed properly. We're talking 0.1ms at most.